# Returning a new list of every nth element in a linked list. C#

Tags: c#, iteration

I am writing a method that takes in an integer "nth" that operates on a linked list of generics and returns every nth element. If the list is 0-99 and nth is 10, it should return a list of 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90. If the list is "a", "b", "c", "d", and nth is 4, it should return "d".

I am using C#.

```
public OurList<T> SkipList(int nth) 
{
    if (nth <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Nth must be positive");

    OurList<T> newList = new OurList<T>();
    Node pTmp = first;
    int count = 0;

    while (pTmp != null)
    {

        if ((count % nth) == 0)
            newList.AddLast(pTmp.Data);
        
        pTmp = pTmp.Next;
        count++;
    }

    return newList;
    
}
```

This is what I have so far, and it works but not for both cases described above. If I initialize my count variable at 0, it works for the 0-99 list, but returns "a" instead of "d" for the letters. If I initialize my count variable at 1 it works for the list of letters. I can't seem to figure out a way to get it work for both lists.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Your expected results are inconsistent. For the list of numbers, you’re accepting `0 * nth` and `1 * nth`, but for the list of letters you want `1 * (nth - 1)` (`d` is at index 3). 

The results you’re getting are correct for your problem description (`a` is at index 0 which is `0 * nth`).

Comment: What is `OurList<T>`, please?

Comment: OurList<T> is the return type of the method. It's a linked list implementation.

Comment: why would you accept the first element in a lists of integers but not in a lisst of strings?

Comment: I'm not accepting any values from the list. Nth is the number that is used to iterate by, essentially. Count is a variable used to keep track of nodes with in the list.

Comment: So why does `0` appear in the numbers list but `a` does not appear in the letters list?

Comment: Is `first` a class member? How are you initializing your linked lists? Is it possible that the `Next` property of the `Node`s is being set incorrectly for the letters linked list?

Comment: If you work with `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>`, this would be very simple - just a counter and `yield return;`. Your callers could simply call `.ToList()` on the result if they wanted a list